# google maps api v3 - waypoints not returned in response object

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the following code, I send the requestObj with one waypoint. But the result show me a path with two legs and zero waypoints. I want to keep the waypoints. What am I doing wrong ?

```
var requestObj = {
origin: new google.maps.LatLng(sn['lat'],sn['lng']),
destination: new google.maps.LatLng(en['lat'],en['lng']),
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
waypoints: new google.maps.LatLng(45.00334,-73.00228),
optimizeWaypoints: true
};

directionsService.route(requestObj, function(response, status) {

if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
   //process data. no way points found in :
   //directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints.length
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the examples in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

> A waypoint consists of the following fields:
>
> location (required) specifies the address of the waypoint.
>   stopover (optional) indicates whether this waypoint is a actual stop on the route (true) or 
>   instead only a preference to route through the indicated location (false). Stopovers are 
>   true by default.

from the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest):

> waypoints | Array. | Array of intermediate waypoints. Directions will 
>   be calculated from the origin to the destination by way of each waypoint in this array. 
>   The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Maps API for 
>   Business customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints > are not supported for transit directions. Optional.

You aren't passing in a valid array of waypoints.  See below:

```
var requestObj = {
origin: new google.maps.LatLng(sn['lat'],sn['lng']),
destination: new google.maps.LatLng(en['lat'],en['lng']),
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
waypoints: [{location:new google.maps.LatLng(45.00334,-73.00228)}],
optimizeWaypoints: true
};

directionsService.route(requestObj, function(response, status) {

if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
   //process data. no way points found in :
   //directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints.length
}});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z494/)